# Ring->module->$R$-algebra, Field->Vectorspace->algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, terminology

I haven't done any mathematics for a long time, and I have forgotten some things. I want to try to remember some of the words and how they interact.

A module is a 'vectorspace over a ring' rather than over a field. So it is an abelian group under addition, closed under left multiplication from a ring. 1) i) A ring is closed under left multiplication and is also an abelian group, then a ring is itself a module over itself? ii) A field is closed under left multiplication from a field, so a field is itself a 1-dimensional vectorspace over itself.

2) An $R$-algebra is a module with a multiplication, and an algebra is a vectorspace with a multiplication. i) I could let a ring $R$ have multiplication being standard multiplication, meaning a ring $R$ is itself an $R$-algebra, ii) I could left a field $\mathbb F$, which is a vectorspace by 1) i), have multiplication be field multiplication, meaning a field is itself an algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a ring is a module over itself. The submodules correspond to ideals.

Yes, a field is a 1-dimensional vector space over itself.

For algebras over a ring $R$, we usually assume $R$ to be commutative. Then yes, every commutative ring is an algebra over itself. (More generally, any ring is an algebra over any one of its subrings that is contained in the center.)

And yes, by the same reasoning, any field is an algebra over itself (or any of its subfields).

Comment: @Surb A basis of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}$? The singleton $\{1\}$.

Comment: @Surb And yes, a ring is a module over itself! Elements of a ring can be added and subtracted, and we can certainly multiply ring elements together in such a way that the distributive law holds!

Comment: I didn't downvote !

Comment: @Surb Okay, thanks. I'm unsure why I got downvoted.

Comment: @JasperLoy You're welcome!

Comment: You shouldn't worry too much about downvotes.  Sometimes good questions and answers get downvoted for mysterious reasons.